# Convertir SQL con group by a LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Estoy iniciándome en el mundo linq, querría convertir la siguiente consulta SQL a linq. Es un poco compleja y por eso me pierdo.

```
select T_Empresas.* , T_EmpresasIndicadoresK.*
  from dbo.T_Empresas, T_EmpresasIndicadoresK, 
       (select IdEmpresa, max(Fecha) fecha
          from T_EmpresasIndicadoresK group by IdEmpresa )T_EmpresasIndicadoresK2
 where T_EmpresasIndicadoresK2.IdEmpresa = T_EmpresasIndicadoresK.IdEmpresa
   and T_EmpresasIndicadoresK2.fecha     = T_EmpresasIndicadoresK.fecha
   and T_EmpresasIndicadoresK.IdEmpresa  = T_Empresas.IdEmpresa
```

Answer (score 1):

Para poder convertir ese sql a linq deberias estudiar el uso de join

[join clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

es mas tambien deberias estudiarlo en sql

[SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Despues debes estudiar el group by de linq

[group (Cláusula, Referencia de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/bb384063.aspx)

[Cómo: Realizar una unión usando claves compuestas (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/bb907099.aspx)

```
var subquery = from k in dbcontext.EmpresasIndicadores
                group k by k.IdEmpresa into g
                select new {
                    IdEmpresa = g.Key,
                    fecha = g.Max(x=> x.Fecha)
                }


var result = from e in dbcontext.Empresas
            join k in dbcontext.EmpresasIndicadores on e.IdEmpresa equals k.IdEmpresa
            join k2 in subquery on new {k.IdEmpresa, k.fecha} equals new {k2.IdEmpresa, k2.fecha}
            select new {
                empresa = e,
                indicador = k
            }
```

en el select no deberias devolver entidades completas